# Fedora 33 | VS Code can't read / open JDK

Tags: fedora, java, visual-studio-code

I'm running Fedora 33 and I'm trying to use Java 11 with VS Code. I've installed VS Code via the terminal, and it's working fine. I've installed the VS Code Java extension pack, the only thing that isn't working is that I can't seem to get the extension pack to find and run the installed JDK. If I try to check my Java version i get this:

```
openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.9.1+11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.9.1+11, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And here's the output of `readlink -f $(which java)`

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.9.11-9.fc33.x86_64/bin/java
```

Here's the VS Code `settings.json`:

```
"java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.9.11-9.fc33.x86_64"
```

I've tried to reinstall VS Code via dnf but it didn't help. Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the java-11-openjdk, and installed the latest jdk-15 and I began to work.